# Why can I have multiple identical binding redirects in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

Assuming I have one `web.config` with the following two identical sections:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>


<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Why does this work, and what will happen if someone changes one of the redirects, such as to `newVersion="4.0.0.0"` instead of `newVersion="6.0.0.0"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have more than one binding redirect defined for one assembly, it uses the first one that it found and ignores all others.

So if you change the `newVersion` of the first one to `4.0.0.0` the runtime will try to load Version 4.0.0.0 of the assembly. The second redirect is ignored.

See also [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx). When I understand it correctly it tooks the first element that has the matching `assemblyIdentity`

> The  elements are order-sensitive.....In case of a
>   conflict in redirection, the first matching redirection statement in
>   the configuration file is used.

Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/433ysdt1(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Do you know why it ignores the others and not throws an exception?